# Redo preprocess on unknown row

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessing, k-nn

I'm trying to write a script to get the most similar rows in a certain dataframe, based on a single row. Using `scikit-learn`

The method I need is `kneighbors`, which kan return the indices of the closest lying rows in my dataframe if I call it on the `NearestNeigbors` algorithm.

The problem is that my data contains a lot of categorical variables, which `NearestNeighbors` can not handle out of the box. In previous projects I always got away with writing a pipeline that did preprocessing and onehotencoding to transform the data to integer/float values. But as not every estimator has a `kneighbors` method, a pipeline object does not implement a `kneighbors` method.

What is the best route to both:

- Preprocess the categorical data so it gets onehotencoded and scaled
- Query an unprocessed row to find the `kneighbors` of the queryrow.

So that unprocessed row should first get processed the same way the
training data was and after that I want to get the `kneighbors` which
show the "original" categorical values (so not the processed ones)

```
cars_data = ...

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=50, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(pd.get_dummies(cars_data))

testpd = pd.DataFrame(columns=['make', 'model', 'body_type', 'transmission', 'fuel','km', 'kw', 'age_months', 'doors','seats', 'color','interior','airconditioning', 'lane_departure', 'led', 'gps', 'panoramic', 'openroof', 'parkassist','soundsystem','standheat','towhook','xenon', 'seatheat','alloywheels'])
testpd.loc[0] = ['bmw',       '116',        'berline',     'manual',   'benzine',   62450,  80, 10,5,5, 'black', 'fabric', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO','NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO'] #should be a variable that can be used to 'query' and get the 50 nearest neighbors

closest_neighbors = nbrs.kneighbors(testpd)
```

This obviously does not work as the testpd is not transformed. I want to do the same transformation as the train data on this testpd, but `OneHotencoding` and the scaling is not 'saved' and I'm unable to reapply that on this dataframe with a singular row.